# R find all possible directions given dimensions

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to accomplish something which I think is fairly simple, but I'm not able to do. I've a function that takes in a number of dimensions as input, say `func(n)`. What I'd like the function to do is to find all possible directions along an entity can move in that n-dimensional space. So for `n=2` I'm expecting the output to be

```
 1, 1
 1,-1
-1, 1
-1,-1
```

The end use case is to say: given a pair of variables, either both can increase, both can decrease, one can increase while the other decreases and the opposite. Its easy to enumerate them out for n=2 but my n is bound to be in the 8-12 range. This would give `2^8 to 2^12` combinations. How is this done in `R`?

I tried the `permutations` function in `gtools` package but that's clearly not what is needed here. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: You may need `expand.grid(rep(list(c(1, -1)), 2))`

Comment: Nice! That works thanks.

Comment: `gtools` will work fine for this... you have to set `repeats.allowed = TRUE`. Like this : `gtools::permutations(2, 2, c(-1, 1), repeats.allowed = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes. gtools also works as @JosephWood points out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(rep(list(c(1, -1)), 2))
```